# Docker error run chmod -R ug+w /var/www/storage Laravel 9

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, laravel-9

I am trying to create a Laravel 9 Docker image (production-ready). But when I run it on my local machine, it throws an error. I tried adding USER root, but it doesn't make any difference.

> chmod: cannot access '/var/www/storage': No such file or directory

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm

# Please do not comment out line below 
# or else this will not be secure image for production.
# USER root 
# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Add docker php ext repo
ADD https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/releases/latest/download/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/

# Install php extensions
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions && sync && \
    install-php-extensions mbstring pdo_mysql zip exif pcntl gd memcached

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl \
    lua-zlib-dev \
    libmemcached-dev \
    nginx

# Install supervisor
RUN apt-get install -y supervisor

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

# Copy code to /var/www
COPY --chown=www:www-data . /var/www

# add root to www group
RUN chmod -R ug+w /var/www/storage

# Copy nginx/php/supervisor configs
RUN cp docker/supervisor.conf /etc/supervisord.conf
RUN cp docker/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/app.ini
RUN cp docker/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

# PHP Error Log Files
RUN mkdir /var/log/php
RUN touch /var/log/php/errors.log && chmod 777 /var/log/php/errors.log

# Deployment steps
RUN composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev
RUN chmod +x /var/www/docker/run.sh

EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["/var/www/docker/run.sh"]
```

Comment: Can you add `RUN ls -al /var/www` before the chmod to verify that there's a file or directory called 'storage'?

Comment: I just tried it and same error I also tried creating the directory but when I do that with  RUN mkdir -p /var/www/storage it throws this error: RUN composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev                                             0.2s

#24 0.184 Do not run Composer as root/super user

Comment: Your question is incomplete and cannot be answered with facts. This line **COPY --chown=www:www-data . /var/www** creates the structure. This line fails because the previous command did not copy the **storage** directory: **RUN chmod -R ug+w /var/www/storage**.  What is the contents of the source directory: **.**?